# Has anyone successfully run Sparkleshare on a Mac?

Tags: mac, file-sharing, sparkleshare

I have Sparkleshare running with a local gitolite server and several Ubuntu clients. Unfortunately I've had no luck with Macs. The file downloads and unzips, but fails to launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there where some build problems in the earlier versions. We've now been running it successfully since .8.2.